# Customize bean validation message?

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

Two stupid questions about bean validation used in JSF:

1. How can I remove the prefix `form1:userName:` from the output message?

   ```
   <h:message for="userName" />
   ```

   Which gets:

   ```
   form1:userName: Please enter a valid username (5-20 characters)
   ```

   I‘d also like to translate the name `form1:userName` to `User Name`, it's easy to implement such translation but I can't find where to build the message.
2. I have a custom validator, say `@CreditCard`, its default message is `{foo.bar.BadCreditNumber}`

   ```
   @interface CreditCard {
       String message() default "{foo.bar.BadCreditNumber}";
   }
   ```

   And the message is defined in `foo/bar/ValidationMessages.properties` in classpath. Now how can I make this properties file loaded in every page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning 1: The error message's format depends on the property javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE which must be specified in a resource bundle of the application like this:

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={1}: {0}
```

The placeholder `{0}` refers to the error message as created by the Bean Validation runtime, `{1}` refers to the component label. So if you don't want to have the label within the message, just make sure that the placeholder `{1}` isn't contained within that property value.

More information can be found in the [JSF 2 spec.](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314)  section 3.5.6.3.

Concerning 2: It's as BalusC is saying, just put `ValidationMessages.properties` to the root of your classpath. More information can also be found in the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-message-interpolation).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the input element's `label` attribute.

   ```html
   <h:inputText label="User name" ... />
   ```

   See also [JSF 2.0 tutorial - Finetuning validation](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#FinetuningValidation).
2. The `ValidationMessages.properties` file has to be placed in the classpath root, without any package. See also [JSR-303 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/edr/jsr303/index.html).